# preventing duplicates infinite scrolling ajax loader

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, infinite-scroll

it might just be too late at night for me to see a clear solution here, but I figured I'd get some thoughts from anybody with an opinion...

the site i'm working on has a long list of user posts. i've got all the scroll event handlers working to ajax in the next batch of 100 posts when you reach or approach the bottom.

**my question is... How do i prevent the following scenario?**

1. UserX visits the site and loads posts 1-100
2. 10 more users visit the site and add 10 more posts
3. UserX scrolls to bottom and loads posts 101-200, which used to to be posts 91-190
4. UserX ends up with duplicates of posts 91-100 on the page

i'll include a stripped down version of my code below in case it helps anybody else along

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"/userposts.php",
    data:{ limit: postCount },
    success:function(data) {
        $("postsContainer").append(data);
        if ( $("postsContainer").find("div[id='lastPostReached']") ) {
            // unbind infinite scrolling event handlers
        }
    },
    dataType:'html'
});
```

in my PHP script I have essentially the following:

```
if ( ! isset($_POST["limit"]) ) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT 101"; // initial request
} else {
    $sql .= " LIMIT {$_POST["limit"]},101
}

$posts = mysql_query($sql);
while( $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts) ) {
    /* output formatted posts */
}

// inform callback handler to disable infinite scrolling
if ( mysql_num_rows($posts) < 101 ) {
    echo '<div id="lastPostReached"></div>';
}
```

This gives me infinite scrolling nice and easy, **but how can I prevent the hypothetical duplicates that would show up when new records have been added to the table between ajax requests?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You define a timestamp from php that indicates the servertime at the time the page loads (eg `var _loadTime = <?php echo time(); ?>`) and then pass this value as part of the Ajax data config object along with limit.

Then on the server side you can exclude any posts that were created after this time and hense preserve your list.

You can also go a step further and use this time along with a basic ajax long polling technique to notify the user of new posts since the page loaded/last loading of new posts - similar to Facebook and Twitters feeds.

Comment: What if someone deletes some content?

Answer (score 2):

Update your ajax request, so that in addition to the `limit` parameter you pass through the current range of post ids (I'm assuming the posts have some kind of unique id). Update your php to take those parameters into account when retrieving the next set of posts.

That is, instead of saying "give me another 100" the request is "give me 100 starting at id x".

(Sorry, I don't have time now to write an example code for this.)

Comment: This seems to me the more robust method (resistent to additions and deletions). I wonder about some implementation of the query. @nnnnnn can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a unique identifier ID for the posts and count backwards.

First visit user requests posts 603-503

Ten users get on the page and add comments so the highest comment is now 613

User scolls down and requests 503-403

Problem solved? :)

Comment: if i were always sorting in reverse chronological that would be fine, but i'm using several filters to sort the posts list so the primary keys of the posts will be in a random order... I considered including in my post data an array of all presently listed posts to exclude from future SQL queries, (ie: 'NOT IN (a,b,....,z)' ), but this array could ultimately have 100's of ID's in it, and this did not seem practical

Comment: Sort backwards from the original filter (ASC = DESC, DESC = ASC) then cut the chunks from the end of the dataset to the front. e.g. your first post-chunk limit is (postnumbers-100 to postnumbers) and after that it's always the index you last delivered-100 to the last index. That way logically all new data is appended to the end of your dataset.